# C++ Introspection: Enumerate available classes and methods in a C++ codebase

Tags: c++, static-analysis, introspection

I'm working on some custom C++ static code analysis for my PHD thesis. As part of an extension to the C++ type system, I want to take a C++ code base and enumerate its available functions, methods, and classes, along with their type signatures, with minimal effort (it's just a prototype). What's the best approach to doing something like this quickly and easily? Should I be hacking on Clang to spit out the information I need? Should I look at parsing header files with something like SWIG? Or is there an even easier thing I could be doing?

Comment: Question is a bit complicated and also quite generic. Did you think about using a compiler like GCC? The good thing is that you have a lot of work already done, and, that, when a new version comes out you can adapt to the new version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GCCXML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html), based on GCC, might be the ticket.
As I understand it, it collects and dumps all definitions but not the content of functions/methods.

Others will likely mention CLANG, which certainly parses code and must have access to the definitions of the symbols in a compilation unit.  (I have no experience here).

For completeness, you should know about our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html)
with its [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html).   (The CLANG answers seem to say "walk the AST").  The DMS solution provides an enumerable symbol table containing all the type information.  You can walk the AST, too, if you want.

Often a static analysis leads to a diagnosis, and a desire to *change* the source code.
DMS can apply source-to-source [program transformations](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) to carry out such changes conditioned
by the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I heartily recommend LLVM for statical analysis (see also **[Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)**)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is hacking on clang and getting the AST. There is a good tutorial for that [here](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html). Its very easy to modify its syntax and it also has a [static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Answer (score 1):

At my work, I use the API from a software package called "Understand 4 C++" by [scitools](http://www.scitools.com/). I use this to write all my static analysis tools. I even wrote a .NET API to wrap their C API. Which I put on [codeplex](http://understandapi.codeplex.com/).

Once you have that, dumping all class types is easy:

```
ClassType[] allclasses = Database.GetAllClassTypes()
foreach (ClassType c in allclasses)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Class Name: {0}", c.NameLong);
}
```

Now for a little backstory about a task I had that is similar to yours.
In some years we have to keep our SDK binary backwards compatible with the previous years SDK. In that case it's useful to compare the SDK code between releases to check for potential breaking changes. However with a couple of hundred files, and tens of thousands of lines of comments that can be a big headache using a  text diff tool like Beyond Compare or Araxis. So what I really need to look at is actual code changes, not re-ordering, not moving code up and down in the file, not adding comments etc...

So, a tool I wrote to dump out all the code.

In one text file I dump all all the classes. For each class I print its inheritance tree, its member functions both virtual and non-virtual. For each virtual function I print what parent class virtual methods it overrides (if any). I also print out its member variables.
Same goes with the structs.
In another file I print all the macro's.
In another file I print all the typedefs.

Then using this I can diff these files with files from a previous release. It then becomes apparent instantly what has changed from release to release. For instance it's easy to see where a function parameter was changed from TCHAR* to const TCHAR* for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider developping a [GCC Plugin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) for your purpose.

And [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is a high level domain specific language (that I designed & implemented) for easily extend GCC.

The paper at [GROW09](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~phjk/GROW09/programme.html) workshop by Peter Collingbourne and Paul Kelly on a [A Compile-Time Infrastructure for GCC Using Haskell](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~phjk/GROW09/papers/02-Haskell-Collingbourne.pdf) might be relevant for your work.